# Is it necessary invoke rcu_read_lock in softirq context

Tags: linux, kernel, rcu

The implement of rcu_read_lock is disable preempt and barrier. And the softirq context will not be preempted.
So is it necessary to invoke the rcu_read_lock in softirq context. Is the barrier important?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is necessary to use `rcu_read_lock` to access pointers that are under rcu protection, even in softirq context.

As you point out, some implementations (ex: TINY_RCU) of `rcu_read_lock` and softirqs make it so that there is no risk of corruption even if you don't delimit rcu read-side critical sections with `rcu_read_lock`. However, that is not a guarantee of the rcu api, only a "hack" because of the specific implementation. This hack could break with a different implementation of rcu (ex: PREEMPT_RCU).

If you wish to treat softirqs as explicit rcu read-side critical sections, you must use the RCU-sched api:
[Documentation/RCU/whatisRCU.txt](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/18558cae0272f8fd9647e69d3fec1565a7949865/Documentation/RCU/whatisRCU.txt#L904)

The following section of an article written by the main author of RCU directly addresses your question:
[Requirements for RCU part 1: the fundamentals - Disabling preemption does not block grace periods](https://lwn.net/Articles/652156/#Disabling%20Preemption%20Does%20Not%20Block%20Grace%20Periods)

I would add that code which does `rcu_dereference` outside of `rcu_read_lock` will trigger lockdep warnings if CONFIG_PROVE_RCU=y.

Answer (score 0):

The rcu_read_lock is to protect some kernel resource being modify simulanteously that causes race condition error.

What a resource must to prevent is: being simultaneously use and modified by two software task/ context.

In Linux, the simultaneously modification may happens in either:

1. context swithing from task to task,
2. context swithing from task to IRQ context
3. concurrent accessing from task in different VCPU cores

Event in a single core CPU environment, the 1) and 2) may still happens. 
On task modifying a critical resource, a software IRQ raise, enter the software IRQ context, run IRQ handler and modifying the same resource simultaneously.

Comment: But the softirq is not preempted by other softirq and normal task.

Comment: the resource is needed to be protected by a lock if it may be concurrently accessed. For example, a thread is modifying a resource and resource is in a quasi state, the software irq entering and modify this resource that cause race conditions.

Comment: Besides, there may be several VCPU concurrently runs software irq and tasks at the same moment. If that resource is not only accessed by a software-irq, should protect it from simultaneously access.

Comment: But my question is that the rcu_read_lock is necessary in softirq context? Because the rcu_read_lock only implement the preempt_disable.

Comment: Oh, i missed this part. you have to use the MACRO: rcu_read_lock_bh if resource is read from bottom half. this macro disable preempt of thread and bottom halves.

Comment: The resource is read from softirq, not bottom half(it will include softirq, tasklet, workqueue). The bh is disabled in softirq context, so i think the rcu_read_lock_bh is useless in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to invoke `rcu_read_lock` in a `softirq` context for document purposes, so you and other developers know that RCU 
protected data is used here.